# Establish connection form CloudFoundry-Service to CloudFoundry-App

Tags: cloud-foundry

Is there a common way to establish a network connection from a CloudFoundry-Service to a CloudFoundry App which the service is bound to.

In typical fashion apps receive their bind credentials and establish network connections to provisioned service for example databases.

It would be very handy to establish a connection from a service to an app, so the service could scrape endpoints that are provided by the app.

Any thoughts on this, why is it / or isn't it possible, why could it be a bad idea.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Normally, you have your service and the application receives credentials from the service through the service binding (i.e. `VCAP_SERVICES`).

You want to reverse this arrangement, which is fine, but the service will need to have some way to know how to reach the applications. The way to do this would be through routes bound to your application.

I have seen something like this done before, this is roughly the process. I'm sure you can adapt it to your requirements.

1. Create a service broker. The broker is responsible for managing service instances and service credentials. The broker is notified [when an instance is created](https://github.com/openservicebrokerapi/servicebroker/blob/master/spec.md#provisioning) and when a [binding occurs](https://github.com/openservicebrokerapi/servicebroker/blob/master/spec.md#binding). Your broker will need to handle these requests.
2. The broker, in addition to its normal responsibilities, is going to need to maintain state indicating which applications have instances & bindings. In addition, the broker is going to need to use the org/space/app guids it's provided through the service broker API and talk to the CloudFoundry API to fetch the routes for the applications that are bound to it. You don't usually get these through the service broker API, but since you want to talk to the applications from the service, you need this information. It gives the service a way to communicate with the application.
3. Your broker may also provide the service in question (i.e. talking to applications), or it can delegate to some other process/container/VM to provide the service. If your service does the latter, then you need a way to a.) create the process/container/VM and b.) pass along the information it requires to talk to your application.
4. Obviously, you need to code the logic that will take the routes for applications that have created instances and bindings and communicate with them.

There can be some limitations with using the routes. First, not all routes are public. For internal routes, it would be kind of complicated to allow the broker/service to talk to the app. The broker/service would need to be an application on CF and you would need to specifically allow that communication (would require more API calls). Second, some apps just don't have routes. Perhaps this won't happen in your case, but it's worth considering. Lastly, not all routes are HTTP, some can be TCP as well. Your broker/service would need to handle both of those.

A variation on the above process, instead of using routes or talking to the API, you could have your broker/service provide some mechanism through the credentials to the application such that it registers itself with the broker/service. Thus when your applications start, they'll read the service info, register with the service and then go about their business. In this way, the application would have some additional flexibility about what information it provides when it registers with the broker/service. The downside is that the app has to do some work to be compatible.

Comment: That kind of describes my first approaches, I was hoping for a secret trick to get around the networking stuff. The big problem, as u also pointed out, is allowing the connections over internal routes. Using the stock network policy server is quite a hustle, the service broker needs to set a policy on every service → container connection than

Comment: The service broker does never now the GUID of an app a service gets bind to does it ?

Comment: Unfortunately (or fortunately from a security standpoint), you cannot bypass the networking restrictions. To your second question, when you create the service instance it's not attached to an app so there's no app guid. When you bind the app to a service, part of that request should be the app guid. See the binding link above and scroll down a bit to where it describes the body payload.